# OpenLayers Proxy isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to get an OpenLayers script working, but it looks like I've made an error. Can anyone help out, please? Here's what I've got at this point:

```
<body onload="init()">
<div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var lon = 12.3113999;
    var lat = 50.5234051;
    var zoom = 5;
    var map, layer;
    OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";

    function init(){
        map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
        layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://ows1.geocontent.de/owsProxy/", {
                layers: 'cascade:ortho'
            },{
                proxyUrl: "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=",    

                getURL: function ( bounds ){
                    var url = OpenLayers.Layer.WMS.prototype.getURL.call( this, bounds );
                    if( this.proxyUrl && OpenLayers.String.startsWith( url, "http" ) ) {
                    url = this.proxyUrl + encodeURIComponent( url );
                }
                return url;
            }
        });

        map.addLayer(layer); 
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);

    }
</script>
```

The script is actually using the client IP - how can we get this script to work with the server IP?

ows1.geocontent.de is set up in the proxy.cgi - but all I can see on my example page are white squares without content. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in the OpenLayers.Layer.WMS, the url already gets encoded. Then you encode it again using encodeURIComponent, which actually gives weird results. So just decode your url first using decodeURIComponent. Thus when you declare your url, put:

`url = this.proxyUrl + encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(url));`

Hope this helps...